# Get Only Tag ChildNodes Not TextNodes

Tags: javascript

I have been programming with JavaScript for a while now but today I just knew that `element.childNodes` returns an array of nodes including the text!!!

I probably have never run with trouble because I used to create the element and append text in paragraphs; but now that I think about it, things could get really messy with text as nodes!

my question is: how can I get only the child nodes that are tags not text nodes.

For example:

```
<div id="e">
   I don't want to include this text right here.
   <p>I want to get this paragraph child</p>
   I also want to <em>exclude</em> this text...
   <img src="image.jpg" alt=" " />
   <a href="google.com">Google</a>
   Exclude this text too..
</div>
```

Therefore, I want to get the `p`, `img`, `a` and maybe `em` objects only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of using `.children` to target only the elements. `childNodes` returns textNodes by default and at times that is very useful, but not appropriate for your example usage.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelector('#e').children,function(el){ el.style.color = 'red'; });
```

```html
<div id="e">
   I don't want to include this text right here.
   <p>I want to get this paragraph child</p>
   I also want to <em>exclude</em> this text...
   <img src="image.jpg" alt=" " />
   <a href="google.com">Google</a>
   Exclude this text too..
</div>
```

Comment: oh thank you! since I learned JS on my own, I have missed these details

Comment: @rz3r0 - If you are ever curious about the native API for JavaScript, the Mozilla Developers Network is invaluable. Just preface searches with *mdn* and then the function you are using. So for example, mdn children or mdn childnodes